# Need more complex custom mapping between Saga data and Saga message

Tags: nservicebus

Let's say I have message

```
public interface ISagaMessage
{
    string Type1 { get; set; }
    string Type2 { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to build Saga for Type1 values OR Type2 values being mutually interchangeable, so that all this 3 messages should work under the same Saga:

```
Message1: Type1 = AA, Type2 = null
Message2: Type1 = AA, Type2 = BB
Message3: Type1 = BB, Type2 = null
```

Desired scenario: First message creates Saga (AA,null), then Message2 get hooked on the same Saga because its pair of type (AA,BB) is overlapped with (AA,null) by element AA. Next Message3 is overlapped by BB value now. If new message Message4 comes in with Type1 = CC, Type2 = null, new Saga will be created.

Only 2 specific type values combination is possible, so that AA comes with BB always, CC always with DD, EE with FF etc. For example, AA will never come with CC. Saga does not know all this pairs of type values combinations upfront, so receiving (AA,null) it can't create Saga based on (AA,BB), BB is not known at this step

If I was able to build custom code to pick up right Saga I would come up with something like this (skipping null check):

```
public Saga GetSaga(ISagaMessage message)
{
   IList<Saga> existibgSagas = GetExistingSagas();
   return existibgSagas.FirstOrDefault(
              s => s.Type1 == message.Type1 || s.Type1 == message.Type2 || 
              s.Type2 == message.Type1 || s.Type2 == message.Type2))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible with the default saga finder implementation, but you can provide your own custom IFindSagas implementation. That will probably do the trick.

Check out documentation at https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/saga-finding.

Samples at https://docs.particular.net/samples/saga/nh-custom-sagafinder/ and https://docs.particular.net/samples/saga/ravendb-custom-sagafinder/.

Comment: Yes, I saw it, I just thought there must be better solution than binding your Saga implementation to database provider. Thanks anyway

Comment: Well, remember that you can have LOTS of sagas. The pseudocode you posted omitted the implementation of GetExistingSagas(). It can be very expensive to load every saga instance to run the matching logic. It's better to use whatever mechanism the underlying datastore provides to do the query as efficient as possible. For example lookup through an index, etc. Better performance, but tighter coupling. Always a trade-off! :)